# How to define properties subclasses in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, inheritance, object

I am new to Javascript and am having some trouble finding the right solution. When defining a new subclass with properties, what is the correct/best practice for doing so? I pulled the code below from MDN, but it doesn't talk about how to pass in properties with inheritance. What I need is a superclass and subclass that have properties that are defined during instantiation. The properties of the superclass need to be available to all subclasses and the properties of the subclass will only belong to the subclass. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
// define the Person Class  
function Person() {}  

Person.prototype.walk = function(){  
  alert ('I am walking!');  
};  
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){  
  alert ('hello');  
};  

// define the Student class  
function Student() {  
  // Call the parent constructor  
  Person.call(this);  
}  

// inherit Person  
Student.prototype = new Person();  

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person  
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;  

// replace the sayHello method  
Student.prototype.sayHello = function(){  
  alert('hi, I am a student');  
}  

// add sayGoodBye method  
Student.prototype.sayGoodBye = function(){  
   alert('goodBye');
}  

var student1 = new Student();  
student1.sayHello();  
student1.walk();  
student1.sayGoodBye();  

// check inheritance  
alert(student1 instanceof Person); // true   
alert(student1 instanceof Student); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables can be accessed using the `this` keyword. You can and should initialize instance variables in the constructor:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var bob = new Person("Bob");
alert(bob.name);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cXLpG/)

When you subclass, the instance variables of the superclass will automatically be available to the subclass.

Comment: Got it, but how do pass in instance variable to a subclass. The above code shows the following concerning inheritance...
    // define the Student class  
    function Student() {  
      // Call the parent constructor  
      Person.call(this);  
    }

How would I go about passing variables to the subclass and have the superclass variables passed in as well?